# Singular value decomposition positive components

Tags: matlab, svd

I am using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) applied to Singular Spectrum Analysis (SSA) of a timeseries.

```
% original time series
x1= rand(1,10000);
N = length(x1);

% windows for trajectory matrix
L = 600;
K=N-L+1; 

% trajectory matrix/matrix of lagged vectors
X = buffer(x1, L, L-1, 'nodelay'); 

% Covariance matrix
A = X * X' / K;

% SVD
[U, S_temp, ~] = svd(A);


% The eigenvalues of A are the squared eigenvalues of X
S = sqrt(S_temp);
d = diag(S);
% Principal components
V = X' * U;
for i = 1 : L
    V(:, i) = V(:, i) / d(i);             
end
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to have the singular components V always positive.

X is always > 0 in my case (and also the Covariance matrix A)

Comment: @gabboshow Are you sure that $V= X'U/diag(S)$ is expressed Ok? How many rows and colums has X? Does X>0 mean that X has all entries positive?

Comment: Well, if all entries were positive, the dot product between any two vectors would be positive. If it were non-negative, you'd have to have the identity, else you'd have two entries in a row or more be positive and the dot product of those columns would be positive.

Comment: Hi thanks, I edited the question....maybe now it is clearer...

Comment: mmm no it is not.. U and V are unitary matrix so that UV'=I

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I think that the equation XT=S1/2UT is not correct..

Comment: I see, for some reason (I guess because of the "eigenvalues of X") I thought $X$ was squared. Anyway, $V=X^TUS^{-1/2}$, so $V^TV=S^{-1/2}U^TXX^TUS^{-1/2}=I$ (up to scalar multiple), so $V$ is orthogonal and can *never* be a positive matrix unless $V$ is $1\times 1$.

Comment: :( Is there a way to decompose a matrix in additive matrices of positive elements? an approximation of the original matrix would be sufficient

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Wouldn't be possible to put some constrains in the SVD maximization/optimization problem? just guessing...I wouldn't know where to start... I am aware of non negative matrix factorization, but I should be able to get the original matrix adding the sub-matrices

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, probably it would be better to specify it in a question. The only thing I can think about at the moment are these nonnegative factorizations.